# Получение данных из вложенной структуры

Tags: golang

```
type User struct {
Id        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
Firstname string             `bson:"firsname"`
Lastname  string             `bson:"lastname"`
Nickname  string             `bson:"nickname"`
Login     string             `bson:"login"`
Password  string             `bson:"password"`
News      []News_item        `bson:"news"`
}
type News_item struct {
Heading string `bson:" heading"`
Text    string `bson:" text"`
Src_img string `bson:" src"`
}


exemple := &User{
    Firstname: "Иван",
    Lastname:  "Иванов",
    Nickname:  "godmodeon",
    Login:     "qwerty",
    Password:  "123",
    News: []News_item{
        {
            Heading: "Макороны",
            Text:    "Не солить",
            Src_img: "upload-759203908.png"},
        {
            Heading: "Макороны",
            Text:    "Не солить",
            Src_img: "upload-759203908.png"}}}
```

Как из такой структуры получить например `Text`?
Пробывал `exemple.News.Text`  но получил ошибку

Comment: ну так News - это массив, поэтому, нужно указать индекс. где `exemple.News[0].Text`. К сожалению, возвращать сразу массив текстов голанг пока не умеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае, для получения каждого элемента массива, его нужно перебрать:

```go
for _, v := range exemple.News {
    fmt.Println(v.Text)
}
```

Или же получить нужный элемент по индексу. В таком случае нужно убедиться, что длинна массива News не нулевая

```
if len(exemple.News) > 0 {
    fmt.Println(exemple.News[0].Text)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Nv9pNLF8cCw

Answer (score 1):

Ты обращаешься к слайсу *exemple.News* без индекса. Если хочешь выбрать все поля *Text*, то пройдись по всему слайсу и клади поле *Text* в отдельную переменную.